# EGit and Stash with Eclipse - SSL hostname verification

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, bitbucket-server

Using Eclipse, EGit and Stash

Trying to push upstream to Stash with EGit, over HTTPS.  Stash server has valid SSL cert but hostname doesn't match.

From command line I can work around with `GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=1`.  What's the equivalent in EGit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set in your repo git config (which is read by EGit)

```
cd /path/to/your/repo
git config http.sslVerify false
```

Or go to `Window->Preferences->Team->Git->Configuration`, and add it there.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was missing - didn't understand that EGit shared same configuration with git command line.  Found it and works.